# Is there a preferred way to switch between units?

Tags: calculations, units

I'm working on a recipe book. Some of my recipes are in British Imperial units, some in American, some in metric. I want to avoid manual conversion as that can produce errors, but I want the book to use one type of unit throughout.

I also want to specify which, at build time, so I want a switch I can set to which of the three to use. So I have one text, no conditionals, but a function that handles the standardization and conversion.

I know I can do this in LuaLaTeX, but I want to avoid external dependencies.

Question: Can I do this within LaTeX' macro language, within the LaTeX environment as a whole (including new LaTeX3 utilities), or am I stuck with external programming?

(And if there's a choice, what is the preferred approach?)

Comment: tex can easily do the conversions (just multiplying by a constant),  You could use lua or expl3 or just simply use primitive tex arithmetic but (presumably?) you don't want exact conversions, but rather a coherent recipe in each set of units, and that might take manual adjustment

Comment: Welcome! Why would you print only one unit? Things are much easier for users if you include the different options in every recipe. Although auto-conversion would make life extremely tricky, for the reasons @DavidCarlisle suggests. You've tagged this `lua` although you explicitly don't want to use it. (I don't know what 'external dependencies' this avoids, but still.) And it has nothing to do with `latex3` as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I would recommend. You *manually* define the amounts for each component in *both* units. For example:

```
\SetAmount{meat}{\SI{2.2}{\lb}}{\SI{1.0}{\kilo\gram}}
\SetAmount{exercise}{\SI{1}{\mile}}{\SI{1.6}{\kilo\meter}}
```

sets up two items: The amount of meat and the amount of exercise in both units.  Then to use these you use `\Amount{meat}` or `\Amount{exercise}`. If `\def\UseMetricUnits{}` is defined the metric paramater is output:

[image]

Otherwise, the imperial amount is output.

[image]

The advantage of this is the amounts do *not* need to be direct conversions which can get messy as this is not a scientific document which would need more accurate amounts.

### Code:

```
\def\UseMetricUnits{}%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\SetAmount}[3]{%
    \ifdefined\UseMetricUnits
        \expandafter\newcommand\csname Amount #1\endcsname{#3}%
    \else
        \expandafter\newcommand\csname Amount #1\endcsname{#2}%
    \fi
}
\newcommand*{\Amount}[1]{\expandafter\csname Amount #1\endcsname}


%% As SI does not have imperial units, set those up here
\DeclareSIUnit\lb{\text{lb}}%
\DeclareSIUnit\mile{\text{mile}}%

%% Declare the equivalent units
\SetAmount{meat}{\SI{2.2}{\lb}}{\SI{1.0}{\kilo\gram}}
\SetAmount{exercise}{\SI{1}{\mile}}{\SI{1.6}{\kilo\meter}}

\begin{document}
For this recipe we use 
\Amount{meat} of meat.
After you will need to walk
\Amount{exercise} to burn of these calories.
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion, it makes more sense to type `For this recipe we use 
\Amount{1} of meat.` to specify how much of ingredient we need.